# adding profileimage node to firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm so new in coding and now I'm trying to write a socialnetwork app but i faced an error and I couldn't find any answer for that.

I could save my profile picture to firebase storage successfully but it I have to connect it to database so that I can use it later.

here is my code:

```
public class SetUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private EditText UserName, FullName , CountryName;
    private Button SaveInfoButton;
    private CircleImageView UserProfileImage;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference UserRef;
    private StorageReference UserProfileImageRef;

    String currentUserID;
    final static int Gallery_Pick = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_up);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        UserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);
        UserProfileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profile Image");
        //storing profile image

        UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setup_user_name);
        FullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setup_user_full_name);
        CountryName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setup_user_country);
        SaveInfoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setup_information_button);
        UserProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.set_up_profile_image);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog( this);

        SaveInfoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                SaveAccountSetupInformation();
            }
        });

        UserProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,Gallery_Pick);
            }
        });


        UserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {
                if(snapshot.exists()) {
                    if (snapshot.hasChild("profileimage"))
                    {
                        String image = snapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                        Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(UserProfileImage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(SetUpActivity.this, "Plese Select Profile Image First...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

    {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // some conditions for the picture

        if(requestCode==Gallery_Pick && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null)

        {

            Uri ImageUri = data.getData();

            // crop the image

            CropImage.activity(ImageUri)

                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)

                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)

                    .start(this);

        }

        // Get the cropped image

        if(requestCode==CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)

        {       // store the cropped image into result

            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);



            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)

            {

                loadingBar.setTitle("Profile Image");

                loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we updating your profile image...");

                loadingBar.show();

                loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);



                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();



                final StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");
                //StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");


                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                    @Override

                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {

                            @Override

                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                                final String downloadUrl = uri.toString();

                                UserRef.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                                    @Override

                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(SetUpActivity.this, "Image Stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            loadingBar.dismiss();

                                        }

                                        else {

                                            String message = task.getException().getMessage();

                                            Toast.makeText(SetUpActivity.this, "Error:" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            loadingBar.dismiss();

                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            else

            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error Occured: Image can not be cropped. Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadingBar.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
    private void SaveAccountSetupInformation()
    {
        String username = UserName.getText().toString();
        String userfullname = FullName.getText().toString();
        String country = CountryName.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(username))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please Write Your UserName", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userfullname))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please Write Your Full Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(country))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please Write Your Country", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            loadingBar.setTitle("Saving Information...");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait for a while...");
            loadingBar.show();
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            HashMap userMap = new HashMap();
            userMap.put("username", username);
            userMap.put("fullname", userfullname);
            userMap.put("country", country);
            userMap.put("status","Hey there, I am Using Pingoo");
            userMap.put("gender", "none");
            userMap.put("dob","None");
            userMap.put("relationshipstatus","none");

            UserRef.setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task)
                {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        SendUserToMainActivity();
                        Toast.makeText(SetUpActivity.this,"Your Account Has Been Created Successfully :) Enjoy!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        SendUserToMainActivity();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(SetUpActivity.this, "Oops!Something Went Wrong:(",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SetUpActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

I would appreciate if anyone could give me solution cause it's my school project and I really need to do it.
I've tried to find answer but i couldn't find it anywhere :(((

thank you in advance.

Comment: you want to save image url in database?

Comment: everything looks fine, what is the error?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @ahmadbajwa  but I can't see my profileimage node in my realtime database

Comment: @AlexMamo  there is no error but there is no profileimage node in my realtime database after running the app –

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: no there is nothing @AlexMamo

Comment: Is your onDataChange or onCancelled even triggered?

Comment: how can I undrestand that? @AlexMamo

Comment: Add a log statement and see if it is triggered.